# Custom Accordion using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, accordion

I'm trying to create a custom accordion using jquery, have read through quite a few solution on stackoverflow but I just can't seem to get mine to work, I believe it has to deal with the .siblings. Anyway, here is my html code:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="current">
            <a href="#" class="current"><img class="icon" src=""/>Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img class="icon" src=""/>Mail</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" title="">Write New</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" title="">Junk</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" title="">Deleted</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img class="icon" src=""assets/colors.png""/>Child</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img class="icon" src=""/>Grid</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img class="icon" src=""/>Class</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery code:

```
$('.menu ul li a').click(function() {

    $(this).next('.submenu').siblings('li').slideUp();
    $(this).next('.submenu').slideToggle();

});
```

The menu toggles open fine, but when I open one, the others won't close.

Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it won't close is because the siblings will look at the same level. So within the `LI` element it looks for more `LI` elements. You wan't the sibling `LI`'s from the parent, and close there child `.submenu`.

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('li').find('.submenu').slideUp();
```

Comment: Hi Niels, sweet it works! Thanks. Been wrecking my brains on parents and siblings

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to close the one that you're about to open on the one that is currently open

$('.menu ul li a').click(function() {

```
$('.current').removeClass('current').next('.submenu').siblings('li').slideUp();
$(this).addClass('current').next('.submenu').slideToggle();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The whole code will be

```
$(this).parent().siblings('li').find('.submenu').slideUp();
$(this).next('.submenu').slideDown();
```

Just changed toggle to slideDown in last line....

I have one doubt ,every anchor will be clickable  using user selector... can we make it only first level anchor clickable .any idea ?